# How to SELECT number from table and use in calculation . Unsupported operand types

Tags: php, ajax

This is the PHP part of an ajax request. The user enters two numbers, via two fields. I can add these two numbers together &  display the total in a field, this works OK.

However, I would also like to add a number that has been retrieved from a custom table to this. So it's two user entered numbers + number from custom table. I get the following error:

`br /><b>Fatal error</b>:  Unsupported operand types in <b>/home/greentes/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jquery_validate_min1/activate2.php</b> on line <b>118</b><br />`

Line 118 is
`$total = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;`

My code:

```
 function myajax_inputtitleSubmit_func() {

 global $wpdb;
$mp_country_table_info = $wpdb->prefix . 'countries '; //Good practice
$mpcountrys = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT labour_cost FROM $mp_country_table_info WHERE id='2' ");


        $nonce = $_POST['nextNonce'];   
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-next-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    $numwelds = isset($_POST['numberofwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofwelds'] : '';
$numconwelds = isset($_POST['numberofconwelds']) ? $_POST['numberofconwelds'] : '';

if (is_numeric($numwelds) && is_numeric($numconwelds))
{
    $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $mpcountrys ;
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
} 
}
```

What is wrong with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$mpcountrys` is going to be an array or an object. In your case, an object, which is the default.

> One of four pre-defined constants. Defaults to OBJECT. See SELECT a
>   Row and its examples for more information.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

It looks to me like you probably want [`get_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) instead.

And I would highly recommend a bit of sanitaziation/validation of your user supplied values before trying to use them.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I've used `is_numeric` on the user supplied values, what else could I do for sanitation/validation please?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the `is_numeric()` but I'd recommend you take a look at [filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) nonetheless.